# How to add data to a SlickGrid DataView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

I'm trying to [follow the simple example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html) of using a DataView with the SlickGrid jQuery plugin. However I can't work out how the data is added to the DataView.

This are the relevant bits of the source:

```
var dataView;
var grid;
var data = [];
...
$(function() {
    // prepare the data
    for (var i=0; i<50000; i++) {
        var d = (data[i] = {});
        d["id"] = "id_" + i;
        ... add data to d
    }
    dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);
```

So the grid is now set up, but how does `data` get bound to it? I can't see anywhere in [the example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html) where it is added, and so I don't know how to add my own data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look further down in the source of the example - you'll find the following lines:

```
// initialize the model after all the events have been hooked up
dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(data);
```

That's where the dataView's items are being set to the data in the data[] array.

Comment: Ah! Why didn't I see that? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I just downloaded a new version today. Mine shows

```
  $(function () {
var data = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
  data[i] = {
    title: "Task " + i,
    duration: "5 days",
    percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
    start: "01/01/2009",
    finish: "01/05/2009",
    effortDriven: (i % 5 == 0)
  };
}

grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
```

})

the data array is were you stick the data.

Comment: You are using the grid backed by a data array. The OP is looking at using a dataView object to replace the data array. Check out the example linked in the Q.